# Outlook playing sounds despite sounds being disabled

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange, system-sounds

Outlook 2007 (12.0.6691.5000) is playing a sound when I receive new emails in my inbox even though I have the sound option disabled. I believe this started happening only yesterday, completely at random, and I'm not aware of any changes that were made to my computer that would have caused it. We connect to a Microsoft Exchange server, and run Microsoft Lync 2013.

How can I turn off the sounds, or determine where they are even coming from?

Update: Sound was enabled in the Outlook web interface. I disabled it and restarted the Outlook, and the sound continues to play. I also disabled the Windows sound that plays when new emails are received (although the tone did not match the one playing through Outlook) and that made no difference.

[image]

Comment: Had you already tried setting all email alert sounds in Windows and Outlook to a blank sound effect, or to a sound effect you would be able to use to identify the offending option?